# how to test spam mail classification

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
user_input = input().split()
user_data = [[]]
# X_test_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
# X_test_padded = pad_sequences(X_test_encoded, maxlen = max_len)
if (model.predict(X_test_padded).all() > 0.5):
    print(f"[{user_input}] is spam")
else:
    print(f"[{user_input}] is non-spam")
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN, Embedding, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

embedding_dim = 32
hidden_units = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim))
model.add(SimpleRNN(hidden_units))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(X_train_padded, y_train, epochs=4, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2)


X_test_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test_padded = pad_sequences(X_test_encoded, maxlen = max_len)
print("\n 테스트 정확도: %.4f" % (model.evaluate(X_test_padded, y_test)[1]))


epochs = range(1, len(history.history['acc']) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(epochs, history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

This is the test code that determines whether the entered email is spam or normal email. But no matter how much text I keep here, it is recognized as spam, is there any solution?

Comment: take thr argmax() of model.evaluate() and then use this. tf.argmax(model.predict(X_test_padded), axis=-1) > 0.5 try this.

Comment: Upvote my comment then kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I have trained a similar model based on a movie review dataset(positive or negative)

```
model.predict(X_test_padded).all() > 0.5
```

The out of above will always be True so the if loop will execute all the time.

Instead use

```
model.predict(X_test_padded) > 0.5
```

For more details please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/39d2579e86f3e214e73373b45687f62b). Thank You.